# waf cannot find an existing library

Tags: c++, node.js, module, shared-libraries, waf

I'm trying to program a C++ module for node.js.
Node is using waf as builder.

I want to check on configure, if the library "sigar" exists.
What I'm trying to do so:

```
def configure(conf):
    conf.check_cxx(lib='sigar')
```

When I run "node-waf configure", I get the following message:

```
Checking for library sigar               : not found
```

But libsigar.so exists:

```
# whereis libsigar
libsigar: /lib64/libsigar.so
```

I also ran ldconfig after installing the "libsigar" library.
The node module compiles, links and works without errors. 
Other libraries like libm, libboost_system and so on can be found on configure.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Is there anything special to do for installing a library than only copying a *.so to the library path and running ldconfig?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it on my own.
Its pretty helpful to run configure with the -vvv option, for very verbose output.

```
20:31:48 runner system command -> ['/usr/bin/g++', 'Release/test_1.o', '-o', '/home/reeaal/workspace/hwmonitor/build/.conf_check_0/testbuild/Release/testprog', '-Wl,-Bdynamic', '-lsigar']
```

When I tried to recompile the programm, I got a linker error which really helped:

```
g++ test.cpp -Bdynamic -lsigar
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.5/../../../../lib64/libsigar.so: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.5/../../../../lib64/libsigar.so: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.5/../../../../lib64/libsigar.so: undefined reference to `dlclose'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Adding a linker flag before checking for libsigar solved the problem:

```
conf.env.append_value('LINKFLAGS', '-ldl')
```

Comment: True, albeit the error message spat out by waf could have been more explicit.