# Linking program with Boost.Asio using waf build system

Tags: c++, python, gcc, boost, waf

I'm trying to build [simplest Boost.Asio tutorial example "timer1"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer1/src.html) (it's in timer.cpp) with waf on Debian squeeze, python 2.6.6.

> root@ds:/var/timer# ls
>
> timer.cpp  wscript

wscript here is a config of waf:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
top = '.'
out = '.'

def options(opt):
    opt.load('compiler_cxx')

def configure(conf):
    conf.load('compiler_cxx')
    conf.env['LINKFLAGS'] = '--verbose -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_system'

def build(bld):
    tgen = bld.new_task_gen()
    tgen.features = 'cxx cxxprogram'
    tgen.source = 'timer.cpp'
    tgen.target = 'timer'
    tgen.includes = '.'
    tgen.update_outputs = True
```

`waf configure` is successfull.

But `waf --verbose build` finishes with error (I inserted `<*>` below to mark a line)

```
Waf: Entering directory `/var/timer'
[1/2] cxx: timer.cpp -> timer.cpp.1.o
[2/2] cxxprogram: timer.cpp.1.o -> timer
timer.cpp.1.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
timer.cpp:(.text+0x103): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
timer.cpp:(.text+0x10f): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
...
Build failed
-> task in 'timer' failed (exit status 1): 
{task 38446736: cxxprogram timer.cpp.1.o -> timer}
<*>
['/usr/bin/g++', '--verbose -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_system', 'timer.cpp.1.o', '-o', '/var/timer/timer', '-Wl,-Bstatic', '-Wl,-Bdynamic']
```

It seems gcc called by waf didn't find boost_system library during linkage.

But everything works fine if I build example by gcc without waf.

```
root@ds:/var/timer# /usr/bin/g++ --verbose -I/var/flake/lib/boost timer.cpp -c -o timer.cpp.1.o
...
<**>
root@ds:/var/timer# /usr/bin/g++ --verbose -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_system timer.cpp.1.o -o timer -Wl,-Bstatic -Wl,-Bdynamic   
...
root@ds:/var/timer# ls
timer.cpp  timer.cpp.1.o  timer  wscript
```

As you can see command line used by waf (marked by `<*>` ) is identical with command line marked by `<**>`. But the result is completely different. Why? And how can I force waf to build that thing? Solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151304/waf-cannot-find-an-existing-library) doesn't work for me too. Also tried

```
...
opt.tool_options('boost')
...
conf.load('compiler_cxx boost')
conf.check_boost()
...
tgen.uselib = 'BOOST'
...
```

but without any effect

And another question. Output of `gcc --verbose` is much more extensive than output of `waf --verbose`.  It seemed to me that `verbose` option must force waf to display all such info. Why isn't that true? waf option -vvv doesn't display this info as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the boost tool, you should check the waf boost example in playground/boost, and you will see that check_boost takes arguments. It will solve your issue.

Alternatively if you don't use the tool, and using a real OS where libraries are set up in an accessible folder, you can just do:

```
conf.env.LIB_BOOST = ['boost_system']

...

bld(
 ...,
 use='BOOST',
 ...,
)
```

Note for your future scripts:

- avoid using CFLAGS, CXXFLAGS, LINKFLAGS as it's not portable.
- don't set out='.' if possible
- use bld(...) vs. the old syntax

Comment: Thank you. But how do I specify flags like conf.env.CXXFLAGS = ['-g3', '-O0', '-std=c++0x', '-fPIC', '-Wall', '-gdwarf-2', '-rdynamic' ]   without CXXFLAGS ?

Comment: in normal cases you don't need to hardcode them in the wscript, and you use CXXFLAGS="..." waf configure ; but there are exceptions of course ;)

Comment: From your example, -std is the only one that is actually *required* to compile the source, so I would put it in the wscript. The thing is that it only works with gcc, so a 'if' would help avoiding breakage with other compilers. I think waf should abstract this one to provide a clean interface, but right now it's not done.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that older Boost 1.42 binaries bundled with Debian were in /usr/lib. When I found that I tried to make /usr/local/lib more prioritive (latest Boost binaries built by b2 reside there). But I couldn't make waf to do that and than just uninstalled Boost 1.42 binaries completely and everything worked after that